# table height adjustment for tablet phone and computer

Tags: javascript, html, css

When I look at the site I created on the computer, the table height is set to full height, but when I look at it from mobile, there is a gap at the bottom of the table. When I look at it from the tablet, this gap is larger. Additionally, when I turn the phone or tablet sideways, this remaining space becomes even larger. I want to automatically adjust the table height according to the device entered on the site. how can I do that.

Comment: You have to have media queries to make sure that you can style for each screen size. Everything coded on a laptop or desktop isn't automatically sized for mobile devices such as cell phones or tablets, and if you want help from everyone, you've got to put your code along with the question